# MKPinAnnotationView draggable option

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, draggable, mkpinannotationview

I am using MKMapView in my iPhone app. I want to implement the pin annotation dragging feature. How can I implement this. The function setCoordinate: shows warning, MKPinAnnotationView may not responds to setCoordinate:. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to that the `MKPinAnnotationView` doesn't implement the coordinate, however the annotation does.

Try using:

```
    [pin.annotation setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)];
```

That should to the trick (given that you call your `MKPinAnnotationView` for "pin".